# Creating an expression with equal to in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying a FOR loop in Linux Shell script to generate a condition to be passed on to a SQL query within the shell script. The following is the portion that is giving error:

```
    > condition=${primarykey//,/ }
    > echo $condition
      cond1 cond2

    > temp=""

    > for i in $condition
    > do
    >   $temp="${temp}c.${i}\=s.${i} AND "
    > done
```

I am looking for the following expression to be generated:

```
    > echo $temp
      c.cond1=s.cond1 AND c.cond2=s.cond2
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    ./script.sh: line 28: =c.cond1\=s.cond1 AND : command not found
    ./script.sh: line 28: =c.cond2\=s.cond2 AND : command not found
```

Could someone help me with the right way to get this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` implies substitution. As in, take the contents of the variable and substitute it into the command line at that point. If you want to *assign* then you must not substitute.

TL;DR: Remove the dollar sign to the left of the equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it.

```
temp=""           
for i in $condition
do
       temp="$temp c.$i=s.$i AND "
done
```